# How to adapt new Python types to SQL syntax in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I'm trying to figure out how to insert compound data types into postgresql from python3 using psycopg2. In this I'm following the example from the [psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#adapting-new-python-types-to-sql-syntax):

```py
>>> from psycopg2.extensions import adapt, register_adapter, AsIs

>>> class Point(object):
...    def __init__(self, x, y):
...        self.x = x
...        self.y = y

>>> def adapt_point(point):
...     x = adapt(point.x).getquoted()
...     y = adapt(point.y).getquoted()
...     return AsIs("'(%s, %s)'" % (x, y))

>>> register_adapter(Point, adapt_point)

>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO atable (apoint) VALUES (%s)",
...             (Point(1.23, 4.56),))
```

But the resulting sql command is incorrect:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "1.23"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO atable (apoint) VALUES ('(b'1.23', b'4.56')')
```

How should I modify the example to make psycopg2 produce the correct sql command?

```
INSERT INTO atable (apoint) VALUES ('(1.23, 4.56)');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the x/y values to strings, they are Byte values (visually marked by the prefixed `b`).
That's a fundamental change between Python2 and Python3.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

def adapt_point(point):
    x = adapt(point.x).getquoted().decode('utf-8')
    y = adapt(point.y).getquoted().decode('utf-8')
    return AsIs("'(%s, %s)'" % (x, y))

register_adapter(Point, adapt_point)
p = Point(1.23, 4.56)
print (cur.mogrify("INSERT INTO atable (apoint) VALUES (%s)", (p,)))
```

returns:

```
b"INSERT INTO atable (apoint) VALUES ('(1.23, 4.56)')"
```